# How to partition in Ubuntu 14.10 after installed?

Tags: partition, gparted

I have new system where installed Ubuntu 14.10, HardDisk - 1 TB, Ram - 4 GB.

Nothing is installed in the OS right now. So, I want to partition the hardisk. I want to make 2 or 3 partitions instead of the 1 right now.

I tried using `GParted` but not unmount current partition and create any new.

I attached screen shot of it.

Let me know if any one has a better idea or has a solution.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you cannot resize or change at all any partition on a storage device that is **currently** mounted. That means that your system needs to be down if you intend to modify the root partition, since you cannot unmount it.
(I found, however, exceptions like `ext4` to what I wrote here. See [this question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime))

You will need to boot in an external OS (e.g. using a live-CD or a USB stick) to perform these tasks. Be sure you do not have any sensible data in the partitions before you start!

Since you are using Ubuntu, I would firmly recommend you to use the `Startup Disk Creator` from Ubuntu and create your own Ubuntu Live CD. Then, use `Gparted` from the live-CD.

I assume that you will find the usage of both mentioned tools quite straight-forward, they are graphical and their GUI is quite simple.

Comment: You can enlarge a mounted ext4 filesystem, but not shrink it. That's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot any Linux from USB or CD and then with GParted change disk size.

This worked for me fine.